# TFS tf lock command not unlocking files

Tags: tfs

TFS in the source control explorer will NOT let me merge from branch b back to branch a because a developer on vacation has some files locked in branch b.

I have manually unlocked these files two ways

1) tf lock $/ /lock:none /workspace:TargetWorkspace /collection:target collection /recursive

2)I have also used [Attrice](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to unlock/undo the locked folders in question.

The source control will still not let me merge, is there another way to shelve/unlock the developers files?

Comment: If the files are binaries, you won't be able to unlock them. TFS keeps binaries locked because they can't be merged. Try using the `tf undo` command instead to undo the users checkout

Comment: @james reed. When looking through the source control explorer it doesnt even show what files are looked. Same with the error output when i try to do the merge

Comment: If you have the TFS power tools installed you can right click in source control explorer and search for all pending changes for all users. You could also try the merge from the command line. That might give you more info. Or you could just use the `/recursive` flag to undo all pending changes